# Filling datasets by using Tableadapters is not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, dataset, tableadapter

I have to develop project using Tableadopter. Actually worked but when I change SQL Server password is not working. So my project totally corrupted also my final year project submitting date on June 10.Suddenly I struggled this Please help me....

**Update:**

```
  private void Form_admin_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LAB-2\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=HRPay; Persist Security Info = True; User ID =smart; Password =smart123");
        con.Open();


        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'hRPayDataSet8.EmployeeQulaification' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.employeeQulaificationTableAdapter1.Fill(this.hRPayDataSet8.EmployeeQulaification);
    }
```

Comment: We cant help you if theres no code, we have nothing to work from

Comment: It worked when?  How?  It does or does not work as shown?  What do you mean by "change SqlServer password"...to or from that which is shown?  It is not at all clear what you are asking.

Comment: @DonBoitnott Actually it worked 2 hours before then I changed SQLServerManagementStudio login Password is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your SQL password back to "Smart123".

Or change the password in your connection string to whatever your new SQL Server password is.

Comment: Yeah Its work.Actually I again changed my old password is working normally. Happy for your help :) :)